# How to check a list of usernames follows X account on twitter

Tags: twitter

I have a list of Usernames
{ user1,user2,users3, user4 }

How do I verify if the users in the list follow a X account on twitter or not?

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/show.json?source_screen_name=AccountX&target_screen_name=user1`

The above works well to check if user1 follows X or not, how to do the same in bulk

Comment: There is no bulk way to do this, you will need to loop through each user in turn and check.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no bulk way to do this, you will need to loop through each user in turn and check.**

> Andy Piper {Senior Staff Developer Advocate at Twitter}